# 'this' is undefined in the next scope

Tags: javascript, scope, this, undefined

My problem is as simple as the title.. I have some code which makes an AJAX call. This code is similar to this ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MZein/8tk6va3u/)):

```
function Test() {
    this.name = "U don't wanna know my name..";
}
Test.prototype.ajax = function() {
    $.ajax("url/path", data, function() {
        alert(this.name);
   });
};

var test = new Test();
test.ajax();
```

In this case `this` is undefined. I could place the following code before the ajax call and use that in stead of `this`:

```
var diz = this;
```

I was wondering if there's another way of using `this` without creating a new variable for it.

Comment: usually people do `var that = this` or `var _this = this` or `var self = this`. More info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In this case this is undefined.

`this.name` is undefined (assuming you meant that), because this is specific to a function's context. Inside that ajax's callback handler `this` no more belonged to `Test`, it belonged to that callback function.

> was wondering if there's another way of using this without creating a
>   new variable for it.

I don't think that without saving the reference to parent's `this` (Test's `this`) you can access `this` that belonged to a more global scope from a function's scope.

Comment: If I change the `name` of `_this`, after doing this: `var _this = this;`, does the name of `this` also change? Or only the name of `_this`?

Comment: You can't change `this`

Comment: I dicovered that by myself already, though.. But thanks anyways :)